# Formfields.BookMarks.get_Item().Checkbox.Value doesn't work (automation word)

Tags: c#, checkbox, automation, ms-word, bookmarks

I'm trying unsuccessfully to change the value of a word Checkbox (from developer tab) via automation in C#. I've tried different ways but the only one I always find when I search on internet is :

find the name of the checkbox by clicking on properties of the checkbox when you are in developer mode

```
object oCheckbox = "Checkbox_name"

document_name.FormFields.get_Item(ref oCheckbox).CheckBox.Value = true/false;
```

But whenever I execute the code I get the following error (the request member of the collection does not exist) who means that there's no checkbox named "Checkbox_name" in my document if I understand correctly.

I also tried to Bookmark the checkbox with the same name and to execute :

`document_name.BookMarks.get_Item(ref oCheckbox).CheckBox.Value` but it doesn't work too...

Comment: I have used UIAutomationClient to successfully click buttons in other applications, fill in textboxes, select items from a combobox, etc... Try using UIspy to get an idea of exactly where the AutomationElement is in the hierarchy of the application. Then use UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes to get to the element that you wish to manipulate.

Comment: is it possible to pass a name to the get_Item method? The msdn article look like that you need to pass an index [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.formfields.item(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inserted a checkbox by clicking on the checkbox shown in the developer tab, then I assume you're using Word 2007 or later.

And, if that's the case, then what you inserted was not a form field, but a content control. Therefore if you enter the following into the immediate window in the VBA editor:

```
?ActiveDocument.Content.FormFields.Count
```

...it will print "0".  Whereas if you try:

```
?ActiveDocument.Content.ContentControls.Count
```

...it should print some number greater than zero, depending on how many of these you inserted.

To insert an old-style form-field checkbox, click the folder-with-tools icon right next to the checkbox icon - this drops down more types of controls, including "Legacy Forms" and "ActiveX Controls".  There is a checkbox in each group, but it's the first group ("Legacy Forms") that will create the checkbox that shows up in the FormFields collection.

I would suggest using the content control if possible, since the old-style form fields may not be supported forever.

Comment: I didn't see your answer, because I finally resolved my problem alone. You are right, the checkbox I was including in my document was the wrong one, I finally find that it was the checkbox from the Legacy Forms group that was working.